# Displaying each polygon segment while digitizing polygon with Polygon construction tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, editing

I am almost positive that I've digitized the polygons and that I have seen each segment shown as I dropped in vertices during the sketch.  I figure that I inadvertently configured something and now I can't get it back.

Once I finish the sketch (by double-click or F2), the polygon redraws and displays as expected.  The symbol has an outline and there is only one feature template.

Here's the polygon, mid-sketch:
[image]

I'm expecting lines for the first 2 segments, but not getting them.

Here's the polygon after I've finished the sketch:
[image]

Here is my configuration while digitizing the polygon:
[image]

And this is the construction tool I'm using:
[image]

Comment: Looking like a video/draw issue to me. I don't see anything option-wise that would affect this. Do you have hardware acceleration enabled on the general options? Does it occur with any file (ie starting a new blank mxd and does it persist)? Does it occur with any layer? Draw order seems to have no effect for me, and it looks like you're zoomed out far enough that isn't causing it either. Tried clearing the display cache? Does it always show just the last two segments? Might it be related to your custom cursor (I think that's what I'm seeing, the blue dot).

Comment: It may seem harsh placing this question on hold but with no answers having been offered in over two years, and only one comment in that time, I think it is time to re-test using the latest version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you have access to, in order to decide whether it is worth you revising it to try and attract an answerer.